# PyCharm code inspection settings for Django

Tags: python, django, pycharm, lint, code-inspection

I like PyCharm code inspection, which helps me to discover my code issues earlier. But when developing with some Python framework such as Django, it warns me for something that is not actually an issue. I don't want to simply disable the inspection for I still need it to help me checking my code. I just want it to be aware of the framework-specific features and specifically ignore those warnings.

For example, for the example "polls" application on Django's official web site (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial02/), it suggests me to oeveride method **str** to return the record content:

File: polls/models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text
```

But when I want to change the the "return" line to:

```
    return 'id:%s, question:%s, date:%s' % (self.id, self.question_text, self.pub_date)
```

PyCharm warns me for the "id" field (pointed by the red arrow):

[image]

But the "id" field is automatically generated by Django. My code runs well with the code.

So, I wonder if there is a way to make PyCharm being aware of the Django behavior.

In this example:

- PyCharm should not warn for code "self.id", for field "id" is automatically added by Django and the code won't bring any issue. Such warnings may obstruct me in finding out real issues.
- But it should warn me for code "self.id_a", "self.id_b", for "id_a" and "id_b" are really not exist, and I need such inspection to check if I miss-spelled the word, so I don't want to completely turn off the inspection.

Comment: Did you, in pycharm, set up a django project, or is it a raw python project?

Comment: @Shadow How to set it? When I click "File" --> "New Project" it just ask me for "Location" and "Project Interpreter", then I will be able to create that project. It seems there is no way to "set up a django project".

Comment: @Shadow OK I googled it, that feature is included in the Professional version, but I'm using community version. I may have to find other ways.